# Count number of items in each row, multiply by their value and then sum over rows, all in one formula

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a table of the following type:

| Price | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 75 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

What I'd like to do in Google Sheets is to (a) sum the number of items with a certain ID in each row, (b) multiply the number with the price in each row, and then (c) sum over the results in each row. So for ID 1, the formula should give 2 x 50 + 1 x 75 = 175, and for ID 2 it should give 2 x 50 + 3 x 75 = 325.

This is straight forward if one breaks this up in two steps by adding additional columns, but I have so many item columns and item IDs that this is infeasible. I looked at ways to use COUNTIF row-wise using arrayformula, but couldn't get it to work in conjunction with the multiplication in each row.

Is there a way to do steps (a-c) in a single formula in Google sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292) and [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294)

with id in row 1 (G1 and G2)

```
=arrayformula(SUMPRODUCT(mmult(IF($B$2:$E=G1,1,0),transpose(column($B$2:$E)^0)),$A$2:$A))
```

drag to the right

[image]

Comment: Dear Mike, thanks for attempting to answer my question! But this formula is not summing the number of items in each row with a certain ID prior to multiplying with the price.

Comment: so you want (2+2+1+1)*50+(1+2+2+2)*75, that's correct?

Comment: Hi Mike, I probably did a bad job in explaining what I am after, sorry for that! To make this clearer, consider only the ID 1. For this ID I want to sum the number of occurrences in the first row (2) with the price (50), and then add the number of occurrences in the second row (1) multiplied with the price in that row (75), so the result should be 2 * 50 + 1 * 75. Separately, for ID 2, it should be 2 * 50 + 3 * 75.

Comment: why 2x50+3x75 ? why 3 ?

Comment: Because the first row contains the value "2" two times, while the second row contains it three times.

Comment: ok i just realized what you call id

Comment: see the corrected answer

Comment: Works marvellously, thanks so much!